# Application of $'$, the derived set operation

Tags: real-analysis

If $F_1=\{1/2, 3/4, 7/8, 15/16,\dots, 1\}$, then $1$ is a limit point. In Stillwell's "Real Numbers," p. 128, he says the $'$ operation (derived set, or set of limit points) can be performed exactly **twice** to $F_1$ since each of its points except $1$ are isolated.

Also he has a picture with the caption: "The set $F_1$ with the derived set $\{1\}$".

My question, please, is what are the two distinct performances of $'$, as I would think one application would eliminate all the points other than $1$.

Thanks

Comment: Or is ' a matter of collecting the limit points?  As F_1 has only limit point the set of limit points is {1}.  Apply it to that set and {1} has no limit points so you get the empty set.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, sorry for the oversight - thanks for correcting it. I understand your answer. Yet what troubles me is the caption I mentioned. Does not the derived set imply all the isolated points have been removed? When he mentions "the derived set $\{1\}$" is he referring to the first application? If you would like to post your comment as an answer, I will gladly accept it. Regards,

Comment: @fleablood, it's very common notation the derived set operation, but I suppose it would have been nice to include confirmation in the body rather than just the title.

Comment: Is F' = {limit points of F}?  If so, then isolated points are never limit points.  So they are allways removed. A disconnected limit such, as 1 in that set, will be kept but in the resulting set it will no longer be a limit point and will be removed when you apply ' a second time.  As to why he would refer to it as "the derived set {1}".  Well... its the set, {1}.  And it was derived from another set.  So it is the derived set {1}.

Comment: Yeah,  I'm familar with the notation but I never thought of as an operation.  So to see the "applying the operation ' exactly twice" threw me for a loop.  Once I looked at it, I realized what it was it I slapped my forehead a few times.

Comment: Okay.  I have *no* idea how I've managed to miss the terminology "derived set" all my math life.  It seems very common.  So "the derived set {1}" means "this is a derived set.  It is the set {1}" which is similar to "the good ship Lollipop" or "my dog Flip".  It isn't "the derived set of {1}" (or "the set derived from {1}") which would be the empty set.

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea why some questions get downvotes.  Try not to let it get to you.

Comment: Maybe include a line defining that F' is the the set of limit points. And maybe include a line that you understand that the isolation points aren't limit points so the first derived set is {1} but you don't (didn't, apparently you do now) understand how to apply ' a second time.  Frankly I think putting your question on hold is absurd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply it once:  $F_1' = ${limit points of $F_1$} = $ \{1\}$.

Apply it twice:  $F_1'' = ${ limit points of $F'$} = {limit points of $\{1\}$} = $\emptyset$.

====

Worth noting that isolated points (points which have neighborhoods containing no other points of the set) and limit points (points of which every neighborhood contain other points of the set) are exact opposite concepts.  No isolated point is  a limit point and no limit point is an isolated point.

So all isolated points will be removed by the $'$ operation.

But once removed the resulting derived set is a different set and what was previously a limit point may not be in the new set.  In this case all the points in the neighborhood of $1$ were isolated points of $F_1$ and were removed.  As a result in the derived set all the former neighborhoods have no points of the new set.

One thing that used to throw me off all the time was I had the mistaken idea that interior points and limit points were somehow opposites.  They are not.  In fact if the space is such that open neighborhoods must contain more than one point (i.e. isolated points are not open sets) then interior points *are* always limit points.  (But limit points need not be interior points.)  My error was that I was confusing limit points with boundary points.  Boundary points are limit points of the set *and* also limit points of the compliment of the set and thus a specific type, and not general, limit points.  (On the other hand, interior points [which in the euclidean topology are limit points] and boundary points [which are always a type of limit point] *are* opposite types of limit points.)

okay... that was a big diversion.